# SQLAlchemy dynamic query using object attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm looking to query an object's attribute dynamically. I will not know which attribute, or column in this case, that I'll be using at the time of execution.

```
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    sku = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    list_price = Column(String)
    status = Column(String)
    url = Column(String)
    special_price1 = Column(String)
    special_price2 = Column(String)
    special_price3 = Column(String)
```

I have a SQLAlchemy Base class `Product` that describes a few attributes, plus additional special prices that differ from the list price.

I then have a `PriceList` class, below, that has access to additional resources and methods that help with reporting and updating columns in the `'products'` table. This class stores information about a unique special price list for all `Product` objects.

```
class PriceList:

    def __init__(self, name, db_col_name):
        # Display name
        self.name = name

        # Used for querying the database for a specific column
        # This will always be one of the 4 price related column names
        # list_price, special_price1, special_price2, or special_price3
        self.db_col_name = db_col_name
```

I later begin iterating over each `Product` and `PriceList` instance.

```
for product in products:
    for price_list in price_lists:
        # Do stuff
```

At this point my `product` object has a new special price, or multiple new special prices, that I plan on updating in the database. I *could* simply add my object to the database session and commit, but I need to get the old price(s) and keep them linked to their respective price lists before I do commit. The old prices are used in a report that later gets emailed to me. What I am doing now is below

```
for product in products:
    sku = product.sku
    for price_list in price_lists:
        # New price
        new_price = product.__getattribute__(price_list.db_col_name)

        # Get the existing special price from the database
        old_price = s.query(Product.__getattribute__(Product, price_list.db_col_name)).filter(Product.sku.like(sku)).first()
```

I feel like I'm drastically over complicating this by using __getattribute__(). It works, but this doesn't seem pythonic. Does anyone know a better way to get the value of an unknown column before you update? Database updates only occur once or twice every ~500 products, so storing each special price in an external variable  while they're being processed isn't exactly efficient.

Comment: Why are you refetching the price if you have the product object right there?

Comment: The product object's price has changed by that point. It has a new price that differs from the database.

Comment: 1. You can access the loaded value of an attribute before you flush. 2. Even if you couldn't, you can always save the attribute yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To dynamically access attributes, you should use the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) builtin.

```
new_price = getattr(product, price_list.db_col_name)
```

If the instance is stale, you should use [`Session.expire`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.expire), which means that the next time you access the attributes they will be retrieved from the database.

```
s.expire(product)

# or only expire price
s.expire(product, [price_list.db_col_name])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My question was unique and confusing but you gave me enough to go on. `getattr()` is the right tool to use for this scenario. I was confused when it came to querying because `getattr()` returns the **value** of that attribute. When running `s.query(Object.attribute)` I've always thought of the argument not as a value but more a pointer based on a class... Thanks for breaking that bad habit. I also never knew about `Session.expire`, good to know!

Comment: Thanks. This helped me realize that what I was looking for is `setattr()`. My case was to set object's attribute dynamically.